# How to compare datetime object as date object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, select

I have table which has datetime column

my table is

```
ID time
1  2014-01-30 12:00:00
2  2014-01-30 13:00:00
3  2014-02-01 14:00:00
```

and I have Datetime object

```
2014-01-30 15:00:00
```

I woud like to pick up the rows which has the same 'date' as Datetime object.

So in this case.

I would like to pick up row 1 and 2

I am not sure how to convert Datetime to date object and compare 'date' in mysql

How can I make it?

Comment: do you want an sql or php solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**DATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to convert `datetime` object in `date`

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA a 
WHERE DATE(a.time) = DATE('2014-01-30 15:00:00');
```

Comment: what is the difference between datetime object and date.According to op's question they all seem like simple timestamp?

Comment: Note that, while this is simple and works, it will most likely ignore any indices on `a.time`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be better as the query could use indexes:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM date_table
WHERE date_column >= '2014-01-30' AND date_column < '2014-01-30' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Use PHP functions to format the date string in such a way that it does not contain time like so:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2014-01-30 15:00:00")->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from yourTable where time >= '2014-01-30' and time  < '2014-01-31'

You can use the Date() function that MYSQL provides but it will add overhead to your query

see http://willem.stuursma.name/2009/01/09/mysql-performance-with-date-functions/ for details

Answer (score 0):

$date is the DateTime object
Since you have a DateTime `object`, you should convert it before using it in the query.

```
$dateYMD = $date->format('Y-m-d');
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`time`) = '$dateYMD'");
```